# What do "answered by..." and "asked by..." indicate?

Tags: support, search

I got three examples below of questions that are marked as either "answered by" or "asked by". I can't quite understand what these texts indicate, sometimes an answered question is marked as "asked by..." instead of "answered by..." and in other cases questions that have no accepted answers are marked as "answered by...". So what do these texts really indicate ?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are looking at a search result that lists two *questions* and one *answer* post.

The 'answered' text is shown on the answer post, because it is an answer, not a question.

The vote blocks to the left also differ between questions and answers; the questions have *two* sets of numbers, the question score and the number of answers on that question. The answer post shows just the answer score.

If you were expecting to see *just* questions, add `is:question` or `is:q` to the search query.